# Syntax error during python module installation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want install ClientForm this is python module but I get this error during installation, someone can help me ?

```
python -m pip install ClientForm
Collecting ClientForm
  Using cached ClientForm-0.2.10.tar.gz (104 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\paulo\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\paulo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tava6mrg\\clientform\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\paulo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tava6mrg\\clientform\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\paulo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-s3ag4apt'
         cwd: C:\Users\paulo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tava6mrg\clientform\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\paulo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tava6mrg\clientform\setup.py", line 13
        False, True = 0, 1
        ^
    SyntaxError: cannot assign to False
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClientForm was [last released in 2008](https://pypi.org/project/ClientForm/#history) on the same day as [the first Python 3.0 release](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/).  It is considered abandoned by its author in favor of the [mechanize](https://pypi.org/project/mechanize/) package.

It is not compatible with the version of Python 3 you are trying to install it on.

Check out the mechanize package.